# How does MySQL replication stay in sync?

Tags: php, mysql, replication

I have 1 MySQL server to support PHP application. The logic in the application requires multiple queries. For example, to add the transaction, I need to create multiple query objects and run those queries separately without using `commit`. Meaning adding transaction data first in the table with one object. And to add a payment method, I am creating the different object.

Right now it's good because I have only 1 MySQL server. What will happen if I have multiple servers (MySQL Master-Slave).

Creating different objects in one operation will call different servers. And because of latency data might not available on another server.

Please advise me to do this correctly. If the question is not clear ask for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about replication or just separate standalone DB servers?

Comment: @Machavity: Replication. I am planning to switch to amazon RDS or Azure MySQL. But, I am not sure current application code and logic will support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't an issue with replication. Let's say you have Query A, then Query B (which relies on A) and Query C (which relies on B).

So you do the straight forward thing and run them in the order A, B and C. Replication puts them into a log in that same order. So when your slave executes them, it will do them in the same way and the same order.

In the even they go out of sync, the slave knows where it last left off in the log and will pick back up there. If you use RDS to set the slave up, this is handled for you automatically.

Comment: Got it.. So, I am assuming there won't be any latency issue even if internally they are using different servers. And if query C relies on B and B is not in server 2 then it'll be picked up from the central log from RDS automatically.

Comment: Also, any thoughts on Azure MySQL? They just launched preview. All my servers are on azure so I am considering that over RDS if it's the same.

Comment: Never used Azure, but RDS does manage slaves for you directly (I would assume Azure does the same). Sometimes a slave will get "stuck" and have to be made unstuck via commands, but that's for a manual replication setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of using RDS, you will query a cluster endpoint. That cluster endpoint will automatically hit the server which is active and create the queries there. 
Once you commit your queries, the slave DB will auto-sync to reflect your changes. That takes couple of milliseconds.